# Isn't the Hit rate*Hit time the access time for the cache in L1, L2, Main Hierarchy?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

50% hit rate, 2 cycle hit time to L1.
70% hit rate, 15 cycle hit time to L2.
100% hit rate, 200 cycle hit time to main memory.

Calculate the Miss time for L1 cache? (In simultaneous accessing.)

since there was no mention of a miss penalty, I did not care anything about it.

I did
Miss time for L1= (Miss Rate of L1* Hit Rate of L2* Hit Time of L2) + ((Miss Time of L1) * (Miss time of L2) *Hit Time of Main Memory))
=0.5*0.7*15 + 0.5*0.3*200
=35.25 cycles

I think Hit Time*Hit Rate= Access Time for that Cache, and if I had to get the miss time of L1 , I calculated total time to access the other 2 memory level.

Please tell me where I am wrong (if any). And if I am getting it wrong, please make me understand the concept.

Comment: If there's a miss on L1 then L2 or RAM need to supply the data.  Odds are that 70% comes from L2 and 30% comes from RAM, at a cost of 0.7 * 15 + 0.3 * 200 cycles.

Comment: so if I had to calculate AMAT of the same system, I am getting a lower AMAT clock cycles than miss time of L1 you mentioned(0.7*15+0.3*200)?